# Using joda DateTime in parameters for native query in spring-data-jpa fails because of bad binding

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data, jodatime, spring-data-jpa

Here are two queries that should be exactly the same except one is marked as native and the other is not. The first one works fine, but the second one fails with `incompatible data type in conversion`

```
  @Transactional(readOnly = true)
  @Query(value = "select startDate from TaskMetrics where startDate between :startDate and :endDate")
  List<DateTime> findStartDateByStartDateBetween(@Param("startDate") DateTime startDate,
  @Param("endDate") DateTime endDate);
```

This generates the query:

```
select taskmetric0_.startDate as col_0_0_ from TaskMetrics taskmetric0_ where taskmetric0_.startDate between ? and ?
```

With bindings

```
binding parameter [1] as [TIMESTAMP] - [2015-02-02 10:57:14.279]
binding parameter [2] as [TIMESTAMP] - [2015-02-04 10:57:14.281]
```

-

```
  @Transactional(readOnly = true)
  @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select startDate from TaskMetrics where startDate between :startDate and :endDate")
  List<DateTime> findStartDateBetween(@Param("startDate") DateTime startDate,
  @Param("endDate") DateTime endDate);
```

This generates the query:

```
select startDate from TaskMetrics where startDate between ? and ?
```

With one binding, which also seems a bit odd (especially why #2?):

```
binding parameter [2] as [VARBINARY] - [2015-02-04T10:57:14.315-05:00]
```

I'm using Hibernate 4.3.8.Final as my JPA 2.1 provider and Jadira Usertype 3.1.0.CR10 for JodaTime support.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug somewhere?

Bug opened here - https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-671

Answer (score 4):

Workaround for the bug:

```java
  public class MyDaoClass {

    // Converter provided by joda time user type library 
    private TimestampColumnDateTimeMapper columnDateTimeMapper = new TimestampColumnDateTimeMapper();

    @Override
    public void doAction(MyObject myObject) {
        Query q = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("MyNativeNamedQuery");
        q.setParameter("date", columnDateTimeMapper.toNonNullValue(myObject.getDate()), TemporalType.TIMESTAMP);
        q.executeUpdate(); // or select
    }
```

Comment: Tysvm! This should be chosen as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

The second one is a `nativeQuery` as i know the will not work with joda DateTime. use `Java.sql.Date` instead.

Comment: So it's a bug in spring-data-jpa? Changing over to use java.sql.Date is not an acceptable solution for me.

Comment: I am not think it is a bug.

Comment: No, it is not a bug, it is because you are using a native query, so jpa does not know hoe to map tha parameter, if you are using JPA 2+ you can do a converter to add new value types to jpa

Comment: How does that make any sense? It's the binding of the types that is failing. That should happen appropriately regardless of the query being native or not. I am using Jadira usertype to create and register the converters for Joda. If I wasn't the first query would fail as well. Perhaps the issue lies in Jadira.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41636326/501113